# Add TEXTAREA to LayoutProcessor

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Hi how do I add a TextArea in my Checkout Page? right now all I can find are ways to add a input field but is there a way to add a text area and not a text field? I'm planning to add a comment field to my checkout but I can't find any solution. Would appreciate your help on this.

```
<?php
$customAttributeCode = 'custom_field';
$customField = [
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'config' => [
        // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
        'customEntry' => null,
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
        'tooltip' => [
            'description' => 'this is what the field is for',
        ],
    ],
    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
    'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
    'sortOrder' => 0,
    'validation' => [
       'required-entry' => true
    ],
    'options' => [],
    'filterBy' => null,
    'customEntry' => null,
    'visible' => true,
];

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line from

```
'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
```

To

```
'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you copy code in **[mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-new-fields-address-form-magento-2.html).** Your code is correct but you are not change some changes based your requirements like :-

```
$customField = [
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
    'config' => [
        // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
        'customEntry' => null,
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
        'tooltip' => [
            'description' => 'this is what the field is for',
        ],
    ],
    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
    'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
    'sortOrder' => 0,
    'validation' => [
       'required-entry' => true
    ],
    'options' => [],
    'filterBy' => null,
    'customEntry' => null,
    'visible' => true,
];
```

I have add some line like :- **`'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea'`** and **`'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea'`**.

**`Why change`**, you want to textarea and you write down input text so.

After you changes run below command :-

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**`OutPut:-`**

[image]

It is helpful link :-

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_custom_checkbox.html**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Yeah I just basically copied iit.. thanks again...

Comment: @MohitPatel please help me on this problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319447/82670