# Magento 2 Remove Add to Cart button and Add New Custom Button

Tags: magento2, module, addtocart

> I am creating a module. I have create one custom product attribute which value is YES/NO.

> **if product attribute value is Yes then Add to Cart Button hide And Show Custom Button**

> **if product attribute value is NO then Add to Cart Button show And hide Custom Button**

***Note: code works everywhere when Add To Cart Button show in Website Not for Specific Page.***

Please Help Me.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: if product attribute value is yes then hide add to cart and show custom button. If product attibute value is No then show add to cart and hide custom button.

Comment: on which specific page you want to display.

Comment: @RohanHapani everywhere in site and when button hide then show custom button.

Comment: You can't able to do this functionality using single file. You need to add code where this add to cart button display.

Comment: i need solution, i do not want overrite much files. I want best way to do that.

Comment: Yes. But, there is no way that manage functionality by single file for whole site.

Comment: if you have solution please give me. but i do not overrite much files.