# How to Replace custom attribute into description attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

How to Create `custom attribute value` **replace into** `description attribute`.

Ex :- My custom attribute all value replace product details tab means description attribute.

My Custom attribute is `local_description`.

Here is My code :-

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();

if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}

$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
// if defined as 'none' in layout, do not render
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
    $renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code))
        ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code)
        : '';
} else {
 if($_code == 'description')
{
   $_code = 'local_description';
}

    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue) :?>
<div class="product attribute <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_className) ?>">
    <?php if ($renderLabel) :?>
        <strong class="type"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attributeLabel) ?></strong>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: where do you want to place your attribute

Comment: Can you specify this in detail what you are looking for?

Comment: i think he wants to add and attribute inside description group

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya  magento 2 product page details tab value remove and replace custom attribute value

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya i dosen't want to new tab but i want replace value in detail tab. Please help

Comment: Please check i have add my code

Comment: i would suggest to remove that tab and then just add a custom tab in place of that and then just call your attribute inside phtml file in catalog_product_view.xml  let me know if this work for you

Comment: Sorry but i don't add new tab . i want to replace value.

Comment: what is the issue into above code?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya not get any output

Comment: please help me to solve this problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319447/82670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module or theme.

And add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getLocalDescription</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">local_description</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is just the sample code, modify according to your requirement.

Comment: your code work in core file but add above code in custom module show this error :- https://prnt.sc/u1etj0

Comment: @MohitPatel It was a tag mismatch issue. I have updated the tag in the answer.

Comment: Yes, i have add after show this error - https://prnt.sc/u1f320

Comment: Remove the as attribute and try. I have updated it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi without enough knowledge as per my understanding am posting this and which will add New Test Description field along with your description please let me know if this what you need or else please update your question with more details

**Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav_attribute
         */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'test_descp');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'test_descp');

        // $statusOptions = 'Rbj\ProductAttribute\Model\Config\Source\StatusOptions';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_descp',
            [
                'group' => 'Content',
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'New Test Description',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );

        
    }
}
```

**Update:-**

place this code inside you **dafault.xml** in custom module

to remove "More Information" tab:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true" />
```

If you want to remove the "Details" tab:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
```